# How to create a re-assignable reference to an immutable class?

Tags: immutability, d

How do I create a reference to immutable classes, but while keeping the ability to reassign the reference, sort of like `string`?

```
import std.stdio;

immutable class Test {
    string test(){
        return "test";
    }
}

void main(){
    auto test = new Test;
    writeln(test.test);
}
```

This causes an error, because the created instance is not immutable:

```
test.d(14): Error: immutable method test.Test.test is not callable using a mutable object
```

`new immutable` doesn't work either, because the resulting variable cannot be assigned a new one afterwards.

`immutable(Test)*` would work, but is there a way avoiding pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use std.typecons.Rebindable http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.typecons.Rebindable.html#examples

```
import std.typecons;
class Widget { int x; int y() const { return x; } }
auto a = Rebindable!(const Widget)(new Widget);
// Fine
a.y();
// error! can't modify const a
// a.x = 5;
// Fine
a = new Widget;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `immutable` in the same way of `auto` to infer types:

```
immutable test       = new Test;
immutable other_test = test;
```

Comment: No. What I need: `magic test = new immutable Test; test.test; test = new immutable Test;`

Comment: Hm. I don´t think this is possible. Because the point of immutable is to guarantee that variable never change during runtime. 
Maybe if you explain your intentions we can solve your problem :)
You said "like string": strings are an alias of immutable(char)[ ]. The chars itselfs are immutable but the string array are not.